# Filtrar info en DF obteniendo en base a cada una de las variedades planteadas las que tengan el puntaje mas alto (y otras condiciones)

Tags: pandas

[Info para testeo](https://pastebin.com/KgFrKzAT)

¿Como puedo filtrar el DF y mostrar de todas las variedades la que tenga mayor puntaje para cada una y otras condiciones?

Por ejemplo con esta linea puedo ver uno por uno cambiando la variedad:

```
dataDos[(dataDos.variedad == 'malbec') & (dataDos.puntaje== 
dataDos.puntaje[dataDos.variedad == 'malbec'].max())]
```

Esto mostraria de todo el DF el Malbec mas caro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo aplicarlo a todo el DF y que me muestre el de mayor puntaje por variedad (Serian los que estan pintados de azul)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACION**

Llegue al objetivo deseado haciendo lo siguiente, pero dejo la pregunta abierta porque tiene que haber una solución mas simple:

```
variedades = data.variedad.unique().tolist()

dfPuntajes = pd.DataFrame(columns = data.columns)

for x in variedades:
    filtroUno = data[data.variedad == x]
    filtroDos = filtroUno[filtroUno.puntaje == filtroUno.puntaje.max()]
    filtroTres = filtroDos[filtroDos.precio_en_pesos == filtroDos.precio_en_pesos.max()]
    filtroCuatro = filtroTres[filtroTres.creacion == filtroTres.creacion.min()]
    dfPuntajes = dfPuntajes.append(filtroCuatro, ignore_index=True)

dfPuntajes['id'] = dfPuntajes.index

dfPuntajes.sort_values('puntaje', ascending=[0]).head(10)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues no entiendo muy bien la solución que das, ya que aparentemente te quedas con la de mayor puntaje, y no con la de mayor precio como pedías en el enunciado.

Además aplicas no sólo uno, sino varios filtros sucesivos. Entiendo que buscas que, si hay dos con el mismo puntaje, entonces quedarte con la de mayor precio, y en caso de que haya también de varios precios, entonces con la de menor fecha de creación. Esto no corresponde con lo que preguntabas inicialmente, pero de todas formas creo que tengo  una solución más breve.

El truco es: primero ordenas el dataframe según el criterio deseado (sería por puntaje descendente, precio descendente y creación ascendente). Después, sobre ese dataframe, eliminas los duplicados mirando la columna "variedad".

Es decir:

```
dfPuntajes = (data.sort_values(by=["puntaje", "precio_en_pesos", "creacion"],
                               ascending=[False, False, True])
                  .drop_duplicates("variedad")
             )
```

Y sale lo mismo que con tu método:

[image: Resultado]

He probado tu método y el que propongo sobre los mismos datos de ejemplo que das. La diferencia es la columna `id` que no sé por qué reasignas.

Comment: Subi el equivocado tiene otros filtros, y lo de los multiples filtros es porque no encontre como hacerlo solo se me ocurrio eso y lo del id lo habia puesto porque como ese df al final termina teniendo 62 datos no queria que esten los id viejos por eso va de 0 a 62. Como siempre muchas gracias!